# Wanting to cut things out of a background on lightroom

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

Hi so I am fairly new to Illustrator. I usually use photoshop. But i am designing stickers. For the purpose I am trying to print on some gold vinyl paper.

So I am looking to make everything that's gold cut into the black background so that theyre transparent and dont get printed in the printing process. I do have 3 layers of the black background as I did use black rectangles to cover the gold inner border. I had tried using path finder but that didnt seem to work
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You don't really have to do this. White is generally non-printing unless you specifically ask your printer to use white Ink. So there's no need to make the letters transparent. Just fill them white, and no ink will be applied in these areas.

Comment: Oh wow didnt know that. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, it's the kind of thing you'd know if you had printing trade experience. Most printing processes do not use white ink - including offset lithography (CMYK and spot colour) and digital printing.  White ink is rarely used unless you need to cover over something, and is a rather specialist request.  Also opaque white ink is not perfectly opaque, so it's usually not an ideal thing to do anyway, expect maybe in some very specific jobs that require it, such as screen printing on a black T-shirt where white ink is often applied first then overprinted with colours so they appear brighter.

Comment: I've added this as an answer now, because I think it's very relevant to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this on a **copy** of the artwork. This is a *destructive* operation and will permanently change the construction. Retain the original art for easier alterations if necessary.

- Select all
- `Object > Expand Appearance` (If Available)
- `Object > Expand`
- Click the `Merge` Button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click a gold object
- `Select > Same > Fill and Stroke`
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key

---

Be aware in commercial printing, on a standard substrate, white is seen as transparent. So you *could* simply change the color from gold to white.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to do this. White is generally non-printing unless you specifically ask your printer to use white Ink. So there's no need to make the letters transparent. Just fill them white, and no ink will be applied in these areas.

This is the kind of thing you'd know if you had printing trade experience. Most printing processes do not use white ink - including offset lithography (CMYK and spot colour) and digital printing.

White ink is rarely used unless you need to cover over something, and is a rather specialist request. Also opaque white ink is not perfectly opaque, so it's usually not an ideal thing to do anyway, expect maybe in some very specific jobs that require it, such as screen printing on a black T-shirt where white ink is often applied first then overprinted with colours so they appear brighter.